# Knowing what file to use with mysqlbinlog

Tags: mysql, mysqlbinlog

I'm using mysqlbinlog with row based replication, running in a cron, and reading from a remote server, which has quite a few log files. I only want to pull logs from a specific range of datetimes, using --start-datetime and --stop-datetime.  I know I can use --to-last-log to have it scan until the relevant file, but what I ideally want to know is the name of the log file that is currently being used.

Is this something I can maybe get from mysqlbinlog, or maybe from the database itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `SHOW MASTER STATUS` on the remote server and it will tell you the File and Position it is currently writing to.

For example:

```
mysql> SHOW MASTER STATUS\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
            File: mysql-bin.000045
        Position: 326704890
    Binlog_Do_DB: 
Binlog_Ignore_DB:
```

Comment: This looks like just what I need, with the exception that I don't have SUPER or REPLICATION CLIENT privileges on the database in question.